Does accelerated network interfaces gets added after all synthetic interfaces are added?
Have a question with respect to Azure Accelertated Networking. When a virtual machine (VM) is created in Azure, a synthetic network interface is created for each virtual NIC. If the VM is configured with Accelerated Networking, a second network interface is created for each virtual NIC.Lets call this interface as vf interfaces. So if i deploy a virtual machine with 3NIC configuration , the VM would totally have 6 interfaces 3 synthetic and 3 vf interfaces. My question is whether vf interfaces are added to VM only after ALL synthetic interfaces are added ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/accelerated-networking-how-it-works
Synthetic interface uses "hv_netvsc" driver and vf interface use "mlx5"
From dmesg log can confirm after hv_netvsc drivers gets added , mlx5 gets added
[    6.818973] hv_netvsc 000d3a0a-6db6-000d-3a0a-6db6000d3a0a eth0: VF slot 1 added
[    7.118991] hv_netvsc 000d3a0a-60d7-000d-3a0a-60d7000d3a0a eth1: VF slot 2 added
[    7.894360] hv_netvsc 000d3a0a-6c51-000d-3a0a-6c51000d3a0a eth2: VF slot 3 added
[   11.129034] mlx5_core 07c4:00:02.0 eth3: joined to eth0
[   11.428013] mlx5_core de6f:00:02.0 eth4: joined to eth2
[   11.730597] mlx5_core e35a:00:02.0 eth5: joined to eth1
I can confirm after multiple iterations of deployment, the behaviour i.e vf interface addition after all synthetic interface are added remains the same.
Wanted to confirm if it is the case always
